# Microsoft Outlook desktop app: How to globally hide all canceled events from calendar?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, calendar

Outlook version: 16.27. Appears to be part of Microsoft Office 2019 with Office 365.

A property of well-written software is that it should "block out the noise". In a nutshell: "Show me everything I need to know, and don't show me anything that's irrelevant".

I'm looking for any way to hide all canceled events. I don't need them cluttering the calendar view, and I shouldn't have to manually clean up each one.

So I searched for "outlook hide canceled events" in Google.

All of the search results are specific to a recurring event (not global). In particular, every instruction I found requires each recurring event to be manually filtered. You can verify this by checking the Google Search I mentioned.

I want an automated way to hide all canceled events from the calendar. Bonus points for a toggle-switch where I can show or hide them at will. Shouldn't be difficult, but apparently Microsoft Office has a thing for making easy tasks difficult. Additionally, I shouldn't have to hide each recurring canceled event on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: You can achive this via View Settings. For your reference:https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/272c3663-5369-4e32-b6b2-eafab837c310/canceled-meeting-sent-from-organizer-but-does-not-delete-automatically-from-invitees-calendars?forum=outlook

Comment: The instructions in that link do not work. The View tab is missing. I searched for instructions on how to enable to View tab and the instructions on Microsoft's support site were wrong.